# Random Sequence of Alternating Increase/Decrease Numbers

Tags: integration, combinatorics, permutations, expectation, random

The problem statement: Repeatedly pick a random number (uniformly-distributed) between $0$ and $1$. Keeping going while the second number is smaller than the first, the third number is larger than the second, the fourth number is smaller than the third, the fifth number is larger than the fourth, etc. In other words, the numbers must alternate between decreasing and increasing. Stop when this alternating pattern is broken. What is the expected value of the number of random numbers picked?

I would think that the problem requires integrals, specifically integrating the expected value over $0$ to $1$. However, I am stuck at arriving at this expected value, since, if $x_0, x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$ is the sequence of numbers picked, the probability is $1-x_0$ that the number of numbers picked is $2$, the probability is $x_1$ that the number of numbers picked is $3$, the probability is $1-x_2$ that the expected number of numbers picked is $4$, the probability is $x_3$ that the number of numbers picked is $5$, etc. I can't figure out how to set up an integral from this. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect the probability of selecting $n$ numbers is simply $2^{-n}$ but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: @Math1000:  it is better than that.  The alternating signs make the odd numbers be smaller than $\frac 12$ on the average, so the even ones are more likely than $\frac 12$ to be larger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A key realization here is that the numbers themselves don't matter, and neither does the fact that this is a uniform distribution.  The answer would be the same for any continuous distribution.  All that matters is the rank ordering of the numbers.  Given that any N distinct numbers were chosen, all $N!$ orderings of those numbers have equal probability.  So the problem reduces to counting the ways $A_N$ to arrange the $N$ integers $1,2,\dots,N$ in such a way that they alternate decreasing and increasing starting with decreasing.  Then our answer is simply

$$E(picks) = 2 + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}P(N \gt k)$$

$$=\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}\frac{A_N}{N!}$$

where $A_0 = 1$, and $A_1 = 1$, and we can easily verify

$A_2 = 1$

$A_3 = 2$

$A_4 = 5$

$A_5 = 16$

These produce the terms

$1 + 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 5/24 + 2/15 + \dots$

consistent with what has been computed previously.  Determining the others is a well-known combinatorics problem known as counting [alternating permutations or André's problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlternatingPermutation.html) whose sequence is given by [AEIS A000111](http://oeis.org/A000111) and known as the Euler zigzag numbers:

1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 16, 61, 272, 1385, 7936, 50521, 353792, 2702765, 22368256, 199360981, 1903757312, 19391512145, 209865342976, 2404879675441, 29088885112832, 370371188237525, 4951498053124096, 69348874393137901, 1015423886506852352, 15514534163557086905, 246921480190207983616, 4087072509293123892361, ...

Using these values gives an expected value of approximately $3.41$ picks, in agreement with simulation.  The generating function for these numbers turns out to be sec(x) + tan(x), so the exact answer is sec(1) + tan(1).

This problem should be tagged for combinatorics, permutations, alternating permutations, Euler zigzag numbers, and Andrés problem.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Yes, I got approximately $3.4$ with simulation. I looked at the OEIS page and the exponential generating function for $A_n$ reduces to $\sec{(x)}+\tan{(x)}$, where $x=1$ is the series that answers the question. So the closed form is $\boxed{\sec{(1)}+\tan{(1)}}$. I find that amazing!

Answer (score 0):

The chance that you pick at least two numbers is $1$.  The chance you pull a third is $x_0$, because that is the room that $x_1$ has to be less.  To make this a probability, we integrate over $x_0$, getting $\int_0^1(1-x_0)dx_0=\frac 12$.  The chance that we pick a fourth is $1-x_1$, but the distribution of $x_1$ is not uniform.  On a relative basis, the probability of a given value of $x_1$ is $(1-x_1)$ or on a normalized basis we have $P(x_1)=2(1-x_1)$  The chance that we pick a fourth given that we picked three is then $\int_0^12(1-x_1)^2dx_1=\frac 23$, so the overall chance of selecting at least $4$ is $\frac 13$

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:
Let $N$ be the random variable giving the numbers of terms in a monotonic alternate  sequence of uniformly distributed random numbers in [0,1).

N takes the values $2,3,4, \ldots n, \ldots $. In order to get the probability distribution of $N$, we denote by $U_1, U_2, \ldots, U_n, \ldots$ a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, $U_n\sim Unif[0,1)$, and by $D_1=\{(x,y)\in[0,1)^2\:|\: x>y\}$, $D_2=\{(x,y)\in[0,1)^2\:|\: x\leq y\}$, the regions of interest within the unit square $[0,1)^2$.

For the simplicity of writing I do not insert the sign '='  to characterize a pair  in $D_2$.

Let us compute $P((U_2, U_3)\in D_2|((U_1, U_2)\in D_1)=\dfrac{P(U_2<U_3, U_2<U_1)}{P(U_2<U_1)}=\dfrac{P(U_2<min(U_1, U_3))}{1/2}$.

But $P(U_2< min(U_2, U_3))=P(U_1, U_2, U_3)\in \Delta_m)$, with $\Delta_m=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3)\in [0,1)^3\:|\: x_2\leq min(x_1,x_3)\}$.

Due to the symmetry we plot the surface $x_3= min(x_1, x_2)$, and compute the volume of the region in the unit cube characterized by $x_3\leq min(x_1, x_2)$.

[image: The surface z=min(x,y)]

This region is a solid pyramid having the unit square as base, and height length equal to 1. Hence its volume is $1/3$ and 
we conclude that $P((U_2, U_3)\in D_2|((U_1, U_2)\in D_1)=\dfrac{1/3}{1/2}=2/3$.

The probability $P((U_2, U_3)\in D_1|((U_1, U_2)\in D_1))=\dfrac{P(U_3<U_2, U_2<U_1)}{1/2}=\dfrac{1/6}{1/2}=1/3$.

By symmetry we get $P((U_2, U_3)\in D_1|((U_1, U_2)\in D_2)=\dfrac{1/3}{1/2}=2/3$.

and $P((U_2, U_3)\in D_2|((U_1, U_2)\in D_2))=1/3$.

It is simply to see that only the present position of a point  influences the probability that the next one lands in some region $D_1, D_2$.
 i.e. this flight from one region to another can be interpreted as a Markov chain having the states $D_1, D_2$ and the transition matrix

$T=\left[\begin{array}{ll} 1/3&2/3\\
         2/3&1/3\end{array}\right]$

Let us denote by $X_n$ this Markov chain.

Now we can compute the probability that an admissible sequence has the length equal to $k$, $k=2,3, \ldots$:

$P(N=2)=P(X_1=D_1, X_2=D_1)=T_{11}=1/3$.

$P(N=3)=P(X_1=D_1, X_2=D_2, X_3=D_2)=T_{12}T_{22}=\dfrac{2}{3}\dfrac{1}{3}$

$P(N=4)=P(X_1=D_1, X_2=D_2, X_3=D_1, X_4=D_1)=\dfrac{2^2}{3^2}\dfrac{1}{3}$

Analogously we get:
$P(N=k)=(\dfrac{2}{3})^{k-2}\dfrac{1}{3}$, for any $k\geq 2$.

We notice that our random variable can be expressed as $N=G+1$, where $G$ is a geometric random variable of parameter $p=1/3$.
Hence $M(N)=M(G)+1=\dfrac{1}{p}+1=4$

Comment: I'm wondering why you think $(U_2,U_3) \in D_1$ is independent of $(U_1,U_2) \in D_2$.  The probability of the former conditioned on the later is $2/3$ not $1/2$ since it is the same as $P(U_3 > min(U_1,U_2))$ unconditionally by symmetry.  FWIW, my preliminary sim shows the answer to be about 3.41 while yours evaluates to 3.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have edited the answer.

Comment: EDITED: Why do you think that the the transition probabilities only depend on the region of the previous point simply because that's true for the 3rd point? The probability for the 4th point will also depend on relationship between the 3rd point and the 1st point. When the 3rd is acceptable, half the time it will be greater than the 1st, and then the 4th must be less than at least 1 of 4 points. The other half the time it must be less than at least 2 of 4 points. P(N>4)=(1/2)(2/3)[(1/2)(3/4)+(1/2)(2/4)]=5/24 which agrees with simulation. I'm confident in my overall sim result of about 3.41.